# PHP parse error /syntax errors; and how to solve them

Tags: php, syntax-error, php-parse-error

im trying run this code but show error :

(Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in D:\xamp\htdocs\Personal\Personal.php on line 21)
my code :

```
    <?php 
        $query = mysqli_query ($connection ,
         query: ' SELECT * FROM menu');
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
    
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li class="list active">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                <span class="text">home</span>
            </a>
        </li>

       <?php  endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are. you using? The `query:` may be unnecessary.

Comment: It looks like you are using outdated PHP version. Upgrade and try again.